# How do I tweak my Flutter Stack widget to not have bottom overflowing?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**[Update] : I got the solution, If you want the code, comment below or if you just want to know I've written it here :**

The solution is to put the **Cover Image** and the **Followers & Following** inside a `Column` (as a single widget) and then put that Column and the `Align` (profile picture) both inside a `Stack`, then set the **Fixed** `heightFactor`.

So it would look something like this :

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[

    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(), //The Cover Photo
        Container(
          child: Card() //The Followers and Following Card
        )
      ]
    ),

    Align() //The Profile Picture having fixed heightFactor
  ]
)
```

This solution is **working on all 4 Devices I have + 2 Android Emulators** (2 have 16:9 ratio, 2 have 18:9 and 2 have 19:9 ratio).

**The problem is following :**

On my device, which is having `18:9 Aspect Ratio` there is no `Bottom Overflowing` issue.

But on devices having `16:9 Aspect Ratio` it's having this issue.

This happens only when I try to set `heightFactor` of `Followers & Following` `Align` widget.

I tried to tweak many things in `Stack` so I could overcome this, but couldn't achieve similar result. So, I'm stuck with this.

Also, as far as I know I can overlap only by using `Stack` widget. If there is any possible option, do say.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 224.0,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage("https://www.eta.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Cycling-by-water-resized-min.jpg"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover
          )
        ),
      ),

      Align(
        heightFactor: 5.0,
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 96.0,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
            elevation: 0.0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Followers",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "Nunito",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.blue
                        ),
                      ),

                      Text(
                        "3000",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Nunito",
                          color: Colors.blue
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Following",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Nunito",
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.blue
                        ),
                      ),

                      Text(
                        "0",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Nunito",
                          color: Colors.blue
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          heightFactor: 2.75,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0.0,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              width: 96.0,
              height: 96.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage("https://cdn140.picsart.com/284302087007201.jpg?c256x256"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill
                ),
                border: Border.all(width: 4.0, color: Colors.blue)
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You've provided the height of widget manually so it'll overflow on smaller screens. So you have to provide the height of widget depending upon the screen. You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` to get the height of the device.

And you can also multiply it with some number to get the height in percentage. For example, if you want 80% height of the screen then you can do `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 80`

Comment: First of all I want to keep the `height: 96.0`. And I also tried what you said, that leads the `follower & following` card to be at random heights on every device, because the height changes with `Aspect Ratio`. The problem is to replace `heightFactor` with something that can work on every device. I know it's possible but how, that I don't.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @yashthakkar1173 is correct. That's one way of doing it. In addition to that I would say to his solution you can use

```
ConstrainedBox(
   child: Card(),
   constraints: BoxConstraints(
   minHeight: 96.0,
   maxHeight: 106.0,
))
```

What I observe is that you don't need the entire view to be in a Stack since it's just the top three widgets that overlap so I would wrap that stack in a column and set MainAxisSize to Min. I've done something similar, or you can set it to max so it'll always fill all the space left over.